# How to turn on my chrome extension in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, vpn

Iam trying to run a chrome extension called browsec in my puppeteer project. The extension is a vpn called browsec. It worked but i don't know how to turn it on automatically
[This is the folder of the extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oX0i.png)

[This is the extension turned off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBHkr.png)

[I want to turn it automatically like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTIiT.png)

[...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W74mS.png)

I tried to edit the files of the extensions but they were too much

This is my code:

```
const Browsec = './browsec'
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra')
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, args: [ '--incognito', "--start-maximized" ], executablePath: 'C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe', args: [
  `--disable-extensions-except=${Browsec}`,
  `--load-extension=${Browsec}`,
]});
const page = await browser.newPage();
```

can you help me, please?